# Operator compactness

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Under which $\alpha \in (0,1)$ operator

$A: L_2[0,1]\rightarrow L_2[0,1]$, $(Ax)(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{x(s)}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}ds$,
compact?

If I prove that the operator A is uniformly approximated
by the operators $(Ax)(t) = \int_{E_n(t)} \frac{x(s)}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}ds$, where $E_n(t) = ${$s\in [0,1]:|s-t|\geq frac{1}{n}$} and I will prove the compactness of the operators $A_n$.

Then I will use the theorem:

"$A_n$ - compact, $A_n \rightarrow A$ converges evenly, then $A$ - compact"
and solve the problem. But I'm stuck on the proof of uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** Consider the operator $T$ of the form $(Tx)(t)=\displaystyle \int\limits_0^1 K(s,t)x(s)\,ds.$ If $$\int\limits_0^1|K(s,t)|\,ds \le a,\quad \int\limits_0^1|K(s,t)|\,dt\le b$$ then
by the [Schur test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_test)  the operator $T$ is bounded on $L^2(0,1)$ and $\|T\|\le \sqrt{ab}.$ If $K(s,t)=K(t,s),$ then the assumptions are reduced to one integral.

Moreover  $T$ is a [Hilbert-Schmidt operator](https://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/hilbert-schmidt-theory.pdf) (hence a compact operator) if $$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1|K(s,t)|^2\,ds\,dt<\infty$$

For the operator $A$ we have $K(s,t)=|t-s|^{-\alpha},$ hence the operator $A$ is bounded.
Indeed
$$\int\limits_0^1{1\over |t-s|^\alpha}\,ds= {1\over 1-\alpha}[t^{1-\alpha}+(1-t)^{1-\alpha}]\le {2\over 1-\alpha}$$
Following OP let
$$K_n(s,t)=\begin{cases}|t-s|^{-\alpha} & |t-s|\ge {1\over n}\\
0 & |t-s|<{1\over n}
\end{cases}
$$
and $\displaystyle (A_nx)(t)=\int\limits_0^1K_n(s,t)x(s)\,ds.$
Then
$$[(A-A_n)x](t)=\int\limits_0^1[|t-s|^{-\alpha}-K_n(s,t)]x(s)\,ds $$
In order to estimate the operator norm of $A-A_n$ we will apply the Schur test to $K(s,t):=|t-s|^{-\alpha}-K_n(s,t).$ We have
$$\int\limits_0^1[|t-s|^{-\alpha}-K_n(s,t)]\,ds\le \int\limits_{-1/n}^{1/n} |s|^{-\alpha}\,ds={2\over (1-\alpha)n^{1-\alpha}}$$ Therefore $\|A-A_n\|\to 0.$ The operator $A_n$ is compact as the function $K_n(s,t)$ is bounded, hence square integrable on $[0,1]\times [0,1].$

Summarizing the operator $A$ is compact.

**Solution 2** is based on a trick. Let $g(t)$ have period $2$ and $g(t)=|t|^\alpha$ for $|t|\le 1.$ Consider the operator $T:L^2(-1,1)\to L^2(-1,1)$ given by the formula
$$(Tx)(t)=\int\limits_{-1}^1f(s)g(t-s)\,ds$$ Thus $T$ is a convolution operator with $g\in L^1(-1,1).$ Moreover $T$ is self-adjoint as $g$ is real valued and $g(-t)=g(t).$ By the Fourier transform the operator $T$ is unitarily equivalent to the  operator $\widetilde{T}$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ acting as multiplication by the Fourier coefficients of $g.$ By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma these coefficients tend to $0$ at $\pm \infty,$ hence the operator $\widetilde{T}$ is compact, and consequently $T$ is compact. Observe that $A$ is equal to the restriction of $T$ to the subspace $L^2(0,1).$